# What is the special meaning of '*' in a Java class path?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, command

What is the meaning of `'*'` ... in this example line?

```
javac -classpath .:classes:/opt/pi4j/lib/'*' ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The wildcard character `*` is quoted to stop the shell trying to expand it at the time you enter the command line.

However, according to [this page from the Oracle Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html) the classpath itself can evaluate wildcard characters:

> Class path entries can contain the basename wildcard character *,
>   which is considered equivalent to specifying a list of all the files
>   in the directory with the extension .jar or .JAR. For example, the
>   class path entry foo/* specifies all JAR files in the directory named
>   foo. A classpath entry consisting simply of * expands to a list of all
>   the jar files in the current directory. Files will be considered
>   regardless of whether or not they are hidden (that is, have names
>   beginning with '.').
>
> A class path entry that contains * will not match class files. To
>   match both classes and JAR files in a single directory foo, use either
>   foo:foo/* or foo/*:foo. The order chosen determines whether the
>   classes and resources in foo are loaded before JAR files in foo, or
>   vice versa.
>
> Subdirectories are not searched recursively. For example, foo/* looks
>   for JAR files only in foo, not in foo/bar, foo/baz, etc.

If you don't understand `*` at all then you need to follow [How to Use Wildcards](http://www.linfo.org/wildcard.html)